# How to get absolute date difference between two dates in PHP?

Tags: php, date, php-5.2

I see there are other posts on this question in other languages, but I can't find one for PHP.  I'm not looking for the difference between two date times, but rather how many days different.  For example:

`2011-08-06 14:05:28`

and

`2011-08-07 08:46:28`

are less then one day apart, but I want a function that will tell me they are on days that are one day apart, i.e. will return a value of `1` for these two dates, and return a value of `2` for the following dates, for example:

`2011-08-06 23:05:28`

and

`2011-08-08 01:46:28`

Really, I'm guessing it must be easy, but I've not worked much with dates before.

Oh, and one more constraint, I need something compatible with PHP 5.2, so can't use `DateTime::diff`.

EDIT: changed to clarify that I do really need a numeric return value, sorry :)

Comment: Possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Comment: not sure... I don't need months or years, just number of days, hence the selected answer (instead of 2 years, 3 months, 2 days, I want something like 795)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i interpret the question correctly, you need [GregorianToJD](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gregoriantojd.php) or mysql [to_days](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days)

Both functions return a [julian day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) for a specific date, which is basically the number of days since "day 0".

Comment: Yes, the `to_days` looks good... I'm not sure about the other, it's not clear to me what value that would return...

Comment: Hey, if this works, it sounds like an easy solution... I'll try it and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$date1 = "2011-08-06 14:05:28";
$date2 = "2011-08-07 08:46:28";
if(date('Ymd', strtotime($date1)) == date('Ymd', strtotime($date2)))
{
    // Same day!
}
```

**Update**

If you really want the number of days between to dates, I suggest you update to PHP 5.3. Calculating the number of days can be rather difficult, especially if you want to be able to handle days in different years.

```
$days = abs(date('z', strtotime($date1)) - date('z', strtotime($date2)));
```

This is the best I can do, but it *requires* that `$date1` and `$date2` are in the same year.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $date1 = "2011-08-06 14:05:28";
  $date2 = "2011-08-07 08:46:28";
  if(date("Ymd",strtotime($date1)) == date("Ymd",strtotime($date2)) {
      // they match

  } else {
      // calculate the difference
      $diff = ceil(abs(strtotime($date1)-strtotime($date2))/86400); 

  }
```

Comment: same as above comment... I'd really like to get a number answer.

Comment: This would return wrong answer for same days in different month, ie for `2011-08-15` and `2011-09-15`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the dates into timestamps. How this is done depends on the format of the input data.
2. Format the timestamps using PHP's [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function (`Ymd` seems like a suitable `$format`).
3. Compare the resulting strings for equality.

If you need the actual difference in days, call `date` separately using `Y`, `m` and `d` as formats, construct timestamps from the result (using [`mktime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)) and divide the difference between the timestamps by 86400 (the number of seconds per day).

Answer (score 0):

```
$secondsApart = strtotime( '2011-08-07 08:46:28' ) -
                   strtotime( '2011-08-06 14:05:28' );
```

Now you can compute any other value based on that:

```
$hoursApart = round( $secondsApart / 3600 );
$daysApart = round( $secondsApart / 86400 );
...
```

You can also use floor() or ceil() instead round() if that better suits your need.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this (using mainly timestamps):

```
/**
 * @param string $date1
 * @param string $date2
 * @return int
 *   Number of days between the two dates.
 */
function date_diff_days($date1, $date2) {

    // Ignore the time part and convert the date part to timestamp.
    $date1 = substr($date1, 0, 10);
    $date1 = strtotime($date1 . ' 00:00:00');
    $date2 = substr($date2, 0, 10);
    $date2 = strtotime($date2 . ' 00:00:00');

    // Compute the difference in seconds.
    $diff_secs = abs($date1 - $date2);

    // Convert the difference to days.
    $diff_days = ceil($diff_secs / (60 * 60 * 24));

    return $diff_days;

}
```

I tried it out with both your test cases and it worked just as you wanted. If you want any changes, you can edit the function. Hope it helps!